# Create an Java array of arrays as Codeigniter insert_batch method requires

Tags: java, database, sqlite, codeigniter, rest

I'm developing an Android app that communicates with an Rest API ([Codeigniter](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)). I'm trying to query into my SQLite database and create an array on format that Codeigniter requires. The insert_batch method requires something like this:

```
$data = array(
 array(
  'title' => 'My title' ,
  'name' => 'My Name' ,
  'date' => 'My date'
  ),
 array(
  'title' => 'Another title' ,
  'name' => 'Another Name' ,
  'date' => 'Another date'
  )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Here is my code so far:

```
Cursor c = db.query(MY_QUERY);
c.moveToFirst();
while(c.isAfterLast()==false)
{
   // TODO: here I have to insert the keys->values into an array of arrays
}

// Here I have to return this array;
return dataArray;
```

My Codeigniter's Rest API code (Controller):

```
public function myController_post()
{
    $dataArray = $this->post('dataArray');


    if($this->myModel->insertMyData($dataArray)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And my model:

```
function insertMyData($data) {
    return $this->db->insert_batch('my_table', $data); 
}
```

The question is: how to create this array of arrays from my cursor?

Comment: You're not expecting your post data to magically be converted into PHP associative arrays, are you? You need to produce data in some text format - usually JSON is used these days - on the client side, and convert that into an associative array on the server side.

Comment: In other words, if my 'dataArray' is an ArrayList<Map<String, String>>, the post data (inside Controller) needs to be converted anyway?

Comment: Yes. How are you going to write it to your output stream if not by using some intermediary format? Java objects exist in the JVM space, to get them anywhere else you need to serialize them, but that works with Java, not with PHP.

Comment: You are right. I changed the dataArray format to JSONArray and inside my controller decoded it. It's working now.